# Grouping documents in elastic search using tokenizer

Tags: elasticsearch

I have no deep knowledge of ES but my boss gave me the task to aggregate/group error messages, so we can see how often an error message appears.

The documents look like

```
{
  "_index": "fluentd.php.error.20191223",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "0zYPM28B9xbIWtpXrXSt",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "message": "WARNING Invalid argument supplied for foreach() /var/www/class/bootstrap.php:9 /product-1",
    "hostname": "webserver-1",
    "@timestamp": "2019-12-23T14:19:04+0100",
    "@log_name": "php.error"
  },
  "fields": {
    "@timestamp": [
      "2019-12-23T14:19:04.000Z"
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    1577109544000
  ]
}
```

```
{
  "_index": "fluentd.php.error.20191223",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "0zYPM28B9xbIWtpXrXSt",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "message": "WARNING Invalid argument supplied for foreach() /var/www/class/bootstrap.php:9 /newsletter.html",
    "hostname": "webserver-1",
    "@timestamp": "2019-12-23T14:19:04+0100",
    "@log_name": "php.error"
  },
  "fields": {
    "@timestamp": [
      "2019-12-23T14:19:04.000Z"
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    1577109544000
  ]
}
```

The culprit here is, both **message** differ but concern the same error in the same file (under different url).

Is it even possible for ES to detect this kind of semantic? The messages can differ in many ways..

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting problem and i dont think there's a straight forward answer to this. One of the ways I can think of is using [Script Terms Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-script)

```
GET /_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "group": {
      "terms": {
        "script": """
        int endIndex = doc['message.keyword'].value.indexOf("/");
        return doc['message.keyword'].value.substring(0,endIndex);"""
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Above would give something like:

```
{
..
"aggregations" : {
    "group" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "WARNING Invalid argument supplied for foreach() ",
          "doc_count" : 2
        }
      ]
    }
  }
..
}
```

You can play around with the script and massage the data as per your requirement based on data analysis and get errortype etc.